# Delete Keyframes in Rig

Tags: animation, game-engine, rigging

I have a rig, and I want to change all the key frames for my right arm. When I delete one, all of them delete across the entire rig. How do I delete for one part of the rig, i.e. my right arm.

Comment: Explain smoother, cause I did not understand the exact problem...

Comment: Is it for game or render? If it is made for game, it is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a concrete animation data keyframes in a ***Dope Sheet Editor***.
In this example I have two bones which have separate rotation animation.

[image]

Arm rotates 60 degrees and forearm rotates 30 degrees.

[image]

If you want to delete a forearm rotation for example you go to the *Dope Sheet Editor*, select the dots (which represent the keyframes) that belong to *forearm bone* and delete them (hover the curor over timeline in Dope Sheet editor window and press <kbd>X</kbd>).

[image]

Now when you play the animation only the rotation of an arm bone remains.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear to me though. Hope I understood it right and this answer will help you. If not I'll delete it.

Comment: How do you bring up the delete keyframes thing? Alt-I removes all in that frame.

Comment: @BlenderDev Press X in the dopesheet, when the right keyframes are selected.